# How to build opencv and boost both in visual studio 2013? /MTd? /MDd?

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2012, boost, microsoft-runtime-library

I use boost library and openCV with Visual Studio 2013 in windows 7.

When I build them, there are many errors like that.

```
opencv_core2410d.lib(alloc.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in structure.obj
```

So, I search this error, and change Runtime Library of project's properties from **/MDd** to **/MTd**.

After that, These error is disappear. But, There are other errors like that.

```
libboost_system-vc120-mt-gd-1_57.lib(error_code.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MTd_StaticDebug' in structure.obj
```

I built boost library like this before.

```
 b2 toolset=msvc-12.0 variant=debug,release link=static threading=multi address-model=32 runtime-link=static
```

I build runtime-link static(**/MTd**) right. 
I don't know why I cannot compile boost with /MTd option.
How can i do?

Comment: um.. I can split this question. But when i search two seperate question, One question's answer is change to /MTd and the other question's answer is change to /MDd.. I want some solution when using both libs together.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CMake you can add the following line to your CMakeLists.txt

```
set(OpenCV_STATIC OFF)
```

so it becomes

```
set(OpenCV_STATIC OFF)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

After that you need to add your OpenCV dlls to the Path. For example:

```
PATH_TO_OpenCV\build\x64\vc12\bin
```

After that it should work using /MDd.

I had the same problem when using OpenCV with Qt and this helped me getting started:
https://github.com/nickdademo/qt-opencv-multithreaded